# use $.ajax() response for if else statement

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I just can't get it to work that I'm using the response of an ajax call in an if/else statement. If I output the response in console.log() it shows that it is correctly set, but the simple if/else statement just doesn't work.

```
function check_foo() {
dataString = {action: 'do_this'};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(foo) {
        console.log('foo='+foo); // output: foo=ok

        if (foo=="ok") { // should be true, but isn't
           console.log('foo='+foo+' -> OK');
        } else { // instead this gets output
           console.log('foo='+foo+' -> FAIL'); // output: foo=﻿ok -> FAIL
        }
    }
});
}

check_foo();
```

ajax.php:

```
echo 'ok'; // This is the result of the call
```

so foo is correctly set as 'ok' (as shown in console.log), but the if/else doesn't seem to recognize it...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Does the `else` fire?

Comment: Are you sure there is no additional space in the response ? Did you try to trim it ?

Comment: You are sure that there is no more than just `'ok'` in the data.

Comment: @MrCode That's how I understand the `// instead this gets output`.

Comment: Do you have the source code for your ajax.php file?

Comment: try: console.log('foo=*'+foo+'*'); You should be able to see if there are any spaces around foo

Comment: I just tried your code, it works fine. I got "foo=ok -> OK"

Comment: `if ($.trim(foo)=="ok")`

Comment: is that everything in ajax.php? because it should work find with code posted. You aren't sending it as JSON or something are you?

Comment: Also watch out for a BOM

Comment: It had really something to do with additional spaces - it workes perfectly now with trim(). Thanks @Johan! Strange thing is I tried the suggestion of @chrislondon and there were no additional spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@johan comment is perfect answer for you i have tried it like:- use trim()
function.js:-

```
function check_foo() {
dataString = {action: 'do_this'};

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "response.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(foo) {

        if (jQuery.trim(foo) == "ok") { 
           alert(foo);
        } else { 
          alert('jgjhg');
        }
    }
});
}
```

now ajax.php:-

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'do_this') {
echo 'ok';
}
```

Comment: Perfect, minus the `alert` statements. For everyone's sanity, learn to use `console.log`.

Comment: That was it - thanks a lot! I just don't know why - console.log('foo=*'+foo+'*'); shows me there are no additional spaces

Answer (score 0):

Tried with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Stack Tester</title>
  <script src=jquery.min.js type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[
        function check_foo() {
            dataString = {action: 'do_this'};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(foo) {
                    console.log('foo='+foo); // output: foo=ok
                    if (foo=="ok") { // should be true, but isn't
                        console.log('foo='+foo+' -> OK');
                    } else { // instead this gets output
                        console.log('foo='+foo+' -> FAIL'); // output: foo=ok -> FAIL
                    }
                }
            });
        }
     //]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
        check_foo();
      //]]>
  </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

with ajax.php

```
<?php
echo 'ok';
```

and it worked fine.

version of `jquery.min.js` is 1.7.1